# How to get the full content from the rss feed in javascript

Tags: parsing, feed, rss-reader

I am displaying the list of news from Times of India RSS feed in my webpage and once the user clicks the list it has to get the contents from the RSS feed and display the entire description in my webpage. I have seen this kind of app in mobile but I don't know how to do it just help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depend on the xml feed you are receiving some allow description while others don't